# Asking for everything "up to" a value [MySQL]

Tags: sql, mysql

If I would like to:

```
SELECT * FROM `Students`
```

...from age 0 to 20, how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Students
WHERE  Age >= 0 AND Age <= 20
```

MySQL has [many operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html) from which you can choose.

Answer (score 7):

```
select * from students where age between 0 and 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with "between". Different databased treat it differently. For instance in...

age between 0 and 20

... some DBs will gathers people with ages of 0-20 but some will gather people with ages 1-19 and so on.

Comment: MySQL is inclusive: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: SQL Server is inclusive: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx

Comment: Postgres is inclusive:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: Sybase is inclusive:  http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug83.htm

Comment: SQLite is inclusive:  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html (I figured, why stop with just Oracle, SQL Server, and MySQL :-D)

Comment: DB2 is inclusive: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_betweenpredicate.htm

Comment: Microsoft Access is inclusive: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP010322121033.aspx

Comment: Never seen any DB that would understood between 0 and 20 as between 1 and 19. An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: SQL-92 dictates that BETWEEN is inclusive: "X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z". (section 8.3)